# Проверка павильности email при onblur

Tags: javascript, html, регулярные-выражения, html5, веб-программирование

Мне нужно чтобы когда фокус исчезает из поля email то должна выполняться проверка на правильность, но у меня постоянно показывает, что email неверный, где ошибка подскажите пожалуйста.

```
<form id="form_id" method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript:return validate('form_id','email');">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script>
    email.onblur = function(){
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        var address = document.getElementById("email");
        if(reg.test(address) === false) {
            alert('Введите корректный e-mail');
            return false;
        }

    };
    email.onfocus = function() {
        document.getElementById('email').value = '';
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Нужно добавить `.value`: `var address = document.getElementById("email").value`

Comment: Зачем проверять на корректность `email`с помощью регулярок. Вообще-то это делается через `type="email"` да или вообще зачем это делать? Отправилось письмо, `email` корректный, не отправилось, его проблемы, а так, все ваши проверки на клиенте можно вычистить и написать, что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("email")` возваращает целый элемент. Вам нужен только текст, доступ к которому можно получить через свойство `value`:

```js
email.onblur = function(){
        var reg = /^[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/;
        var address = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(address);
        if(!reg.test(address)) {
            alert('Введите корректный e-mail');
            return false;
        }

    };
    email.onfocus = function() {
        document.getElementById('email').value = '';
    };
```

```html
<form id="form_id" method="post" action="" onsubmit="javascript:return validate('form_id','email');">
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Предлагаю также заменит `([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+` на `[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+`, чтобы движок регулярных выражений не перезаписывал каждый найденный символ в буфере первой захватывающей группы (которую следует просто удалить, также как и вторую, так как они не используются далее в коде).

Кстати, если вы хотите использовать регулярное выражение, которое следует логике `type="email"`, замените своё выражение следующим

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

См. [документацию по HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-e-mail)

Answer (score -1):

Для адреса электронной почты лучше использовать `[type=email]`, регулярное выражение для проверки задавать через атрибут `pattern`, проверять валидность после потери фокуса событием `change`.

```js
var mailInput = document.querySelector('[type=email]');
mailInput.addEventListener('change',function(){
  if(this.validity.valid){
    console.log('Валидно')
  }else{
    console.log('Невалидно')
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="email" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9_.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$" />
```

Comment: Это не кроссбраузерный подход и он не будет работать в Safari.
http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern

Comment: @ CoonJS , это смотря какую версию Safari поддерживать: https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern